# Is the signature of Hamcrest allOf() wrong?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

This matcher checks a collection of matchers and succeeds if they all succeed.

The signature reads:

```
public static <T> Matcher<T> allOf(Iterable<Matcher<? extends T>> matchers)
```

Why does this take an iterable of 
     `Matcher<? extends T>`

and not 
     `Matcher<? super t>`

If it's correct as is, please explain.

The type will be inferred from the object being matched (tested), so I would expect the iterable to hold matchers compatible with the object being matched or any superclass thereof.  Similarly, allowing the iterable to hold matchers that are only compatible with a subclass seems wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(answering own question)

My bad - was accidentally using old version.  This was [fixed in 2007](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/diff?spec=svn194&r=194&format=side&path=/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/AllOf.java) in Hamcrest 1.2.  But the old "extends" version was included in JUnit until JUnit 4.11, released December 2012.